# adding external project in spring mvc maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I am new in Spring MVC. I am trying to add my core Maven project into Spring MVC Maven project. It build successfully and i can see the respective jar files in "target\project.war\WEB-INF\lib" but it throws error on glassfish console.

> Info:   visiting unvisited references Info:   visiting unvisited
>   references Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [IDSNGWeb]
>   Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EnvironmentProperty.isConflictResourceGroup(EnvironmentProperty.java:433)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.ServiceReferenceDescriptor.isConflict(ServiceReferenceDescriptor.java:699)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor.WebFragmentDescriptor.combineServiceReferenceDescriptors(WebFragmentDescriptor.java:210)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor.WebBundleDescriptorImpl.addJndiNameEnvironment(WebBundleDescriptorImpl.java:277)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor.WebBundleDescriptorImpl.addCommonWebBundleDescriptor(WebBundleDescriptorImpl.java:268)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor.WebBundleDescriptorImpl.addWebBundleDescriptor(WebBundleDescriptorImpl.java:156)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:354)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:91)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:421)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Severe:   Exception while deploying the app

i am not able to add any maven project or jar files. Highly possible i am not doing right on adding dependency. If anyone could help me with it. Thanks in advance.

Below is my POM file.

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.agnisys.idsng</groupId>
<artifactId>IDSNGWeb</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>IDSNGWeb</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.directory>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.directory>
    <!-- <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>-->
    <spring.version>3.2.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <!--  <property name="AS_HOME" value="C:\Users\Agnisys56\Documents\GitHub\IDS-NextGen\IDSNGWeb\src\main\webapp"/> -->
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.agnisys</groupId>
        <artifactId>IDSManager</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.directory}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: share your entire pom.xml

Comment: i have update it with my complete pom file

Answer (score 0):

There is a way I've used before is to create a main project which contains your two projects, The main project should have the main POM file that have shared dependencies between of all child projects, and each of your projects should have their own POM configuration. You can then import in the spring MVC project POM your second child project. 
More details :

> https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-parent-child-pom-example/

You can also use something called Multi-module project :

> https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module
>
> https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-how-to-create-a-multi-module-project/

Comment: Yes. But i do not repeat any common dependencies.

Comment: You don't have to , its just an option

Comment: but this still does not resolve my exception. any other suggestion?